# i am not able to redirect to another page in ionic , i am using symfony as a backend service and ionic as a front-end site..

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, symfony, ionic-framework

i am not able to redirect to another page in ionic , i am using symfony as a backend service and ionic as a front-end where i have to bind data which i am getting from database site..

this is my controller ...

```
$scope.getParentProfile = function() {
    DashBoardServices.getParentProfileDetails("57cd019afbe0855c0e8b4568")
        .then(function (data) {
            //grant access to the app
            if(data.Message == 1) {
                $state.go("home");
            }else{
                $state.go("dash");
            }

        });
},
```

and this is my service

app.factory('DashBoardServices', function($http) {

```
 return {
         getAllChild: function (parentId) {
         return $http.post('http://127.1.1.0/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/web/app_dev.php/api/all/child', {
         parentId: parentId

         });
         },
```

any one please resolve this issue where is the problem..

Comment: i have also used $location.path method for redirection but the problem is when ever i have clicked on the button , page will not get redirect to another page...

Comment: Page redirection has been the bane of my existence in multiple programming languages and frameworks.